# OData V4 Changes Are Not Reflected in Other Bindings

Tags: odata, sapui5

I created a UI5 master-detail page:

#### Master

```xml
<List items="{som>/Users}">
  <StandardListItem
    type="Navigation"
    press="onItemPress"
    title="{som>UserName}"
  />
</List>
```

```js
onItemPress: function(oEvent) {
  var oUserContext = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("som");
  var oUser = oUserContext.getObject();
  this.getRouter().navTo("userDetails", {userId: oUser.Id});
}
```

#### Detail

```js
onInit: function () {
  var route = this.getRouter().getRoute("userDetails");
  route.attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
},

_onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
  var sUserId = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").userId;
  this.getView().bindElement({
    path: "som>/Users('"+sUserId+"')",
    model: "som"
  });
},

reload: function() {
  this.getView().getModel("som").refresh();
},
```

```xml
<fLayout:SimpleForm id="userForm">
  <Button text="reload" press="reload"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>settings.user.id}"/>
  <Input editable="false" value="{som>Id}"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>settings.user.username}"/>
  <Input value="{som>UserName}"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>settings.user.email}"/>
  <Input value="{som>Email}"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>settings.user.firstname}"/>
  <Input value="{som>FirstName}"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>settings.user.lastname}"/>
  <Input value="{som>LastName}"/>
</fLayout:SimpleForm>
```

Everything is working fine. But when I change a user in the detail view, it is being updated but not in the master view! With the reload method, I can manually refresh it. But how can I fire this automatically after a change? Can I bind a change event on the SimpleForm?

Comment: According to the [UI5 roadmap](https://roadmaps.sap.com/board?PRODUCT=73554900100800001361&range=FIRST-LAST#;INNO=6EAE8B28C5D91EDABEB530FB8D6620ED), the synchronization between list and detail is planned for Q2 of this year.

Answer (score 5):

See https://embed.plnkr.co/qatUyq/?show=preview:%3Fsap-ui-xx-componentPreload%3Doff

[image: https://embed.plnkr.co/qatUyq/]
<sup>Minimal example using the OData V4 *TripPin* service</sup>

Keep in mind that `v4.ODataModel` is still work in progress. The **synchronization mode has to be `"None"`** currently.

> #### [*synchronizationMode*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel#constructor)
>
> Controls synchronization between different bindings which refer to the same data for the case data changes in one binding. Must be set to 'None' which means **bindings are not synchronized at all** [...].

<sup>***Update:** According to the [UI5 roadmap](https://roadmaps.sap.com/board?PRODUCT=73554900100800001361&range=FIRST-LAST#;INNO=6EAE8B28C5D91EDABEB530FB8D6620ED) (SAP Community account required), the data binding synchronization support is "planned for Q2 2021".*</sup>

Therefore, the application itself has to identify related bindings and refresh them manually. To make it efficient, we can send such GET requests together with the update request via batch group ID which is what `v2.ODataModel` automatically does (unless `refreshAfterChange` is disabled).

In the example above, I used the following settings and APIs:

1. `$$updateGroupId: "myGroupId"` for the context binding (detail page).
2. After user presses <kbd>Submit</kbd>, call [`refresh("myGroupId")`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding#methods/refresh) from the list binding (master list).
3. And finally [`submitBatch("myGroupId")`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel#methods/submitBatch).

If we then inspect the request payload, we can [see that the PATCH and GET requests are bundled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxX5a.gif) together. Hence, the master list is refreshed at the same time.

---

## Q&A

1. What is the default binding mode in `v4.ODataModel`?

   - [It's `"TwoWay"`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/5fdbf3e9846a72ca29f2db4ed7b457f955d38c46/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/v4/ODataModel.js#L334) (Unless `sharedRequests` is enabled) - The UI changes the model data and the other way around. When the change is **not** stored in a batch queue, the corresponding request is sent to the backend immediately.
2. How do I know if I'm using batch mode or not?

   - Pretty much all bindings in v4, as well as the model itself, support the parameter `$$groupId` for read, and certain bindings support `$$updateGroupId` for update requests.

     - If the ID is set to `"$direct"`, the corresponding requests are sent *directly* without batch. Those requests are easier to diagnose and [cacheable](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/cacheable) by the browser.
     - If the ID is a custom string (like in the example above), the corresponding requests are to be sent explicitly by the API `submitBatch`.
     - If there is no such ID defined, the default value is set to `"$auto"`, meaning by default, requests are sent as batch automatically after all the related controls are rerendered.
   - Take a look at the documentation topic [Batch Control](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/74142a38e3d4467c8d6a70b28764048f).
3. How can the application make sure that refreshing the list is always applied after the update is done even though those two requests (GET & PATCH) are bundled as one?

   - The model already takes care of this:

     > The OData V4 model automatically puts all **non**-GET requests into a single change set, which is located at the beginning of a batch request. All GET requests are put **after** it.
4. Why can I call `submitBatch` without adding the groups to "deferred groups" beforehand like I did with `v2.ODataModel`?

   - V4 has simplified dealing with batch groups:

     > Application groups are **by default deferred**; there is no need to set or get deferred groups. You just need the `submitBatch` method on the model to control execution of the batch. [[doc]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/abd4d7c7548d4c29ab8364d3904a6d74)
5. Models usually support events such as `requestSent` and `requestCompleted`. Why can't I make use of them in `v4.ODataModel`?

   - It's just not supported by design. See [Unsupported Superclass Methods and Events](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/1232241b99d7437ba3614698d53dfa4b).

---

Hope I made some things clearer. The latest documentation about OData V4 in UI5 can be found at: https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/5de13cf4dd1f4a3480f7e2eaaee3f5b8

Answer (score 0):

V4 model works with promise.

When submit the changes you can use .then(), so you can refresh the model.

```
...
            var oView = this.getView();

            function refreshModel() {
                oView.getModel().refresh();
            }

            oView.getModel().submitBatch(sGroupId).then(refreshModel);
...
```

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel/methods/submitBatch

Comment: But i never call submitBatch. I think oData v4 doing this by itself.

Comment: You want update master view before send changes to backend? I think it isn't automatic, because it's in different contexts.

Comment: Did you try the event dataReceived of ContextBinding?
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataContextBinding/events/Summary

Comment: Yes i tryed it, but this event isn't triggerd by an property update